# What shall i remove from the code to disable mobile responsive

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, responsive

Please help what to remove from the code to disable mobile responsive site, i only need desktop version. i already removed to view port.

I have 2 CSS files, i am giving the online link here.

Main.CSS
http://iibmdxb.com/css/main.css

Style.CSS
http://iibmdxb.com/css/styles.css

and the website is iibmdxb.com

i cannot put all the code in body because it goes too long. 
please help me to remove the codes from css for avoid mobile responsive

Thank you

I am want to put of responsive because responsive is not properly working for my site. after trying hard i am not able to resolve it so i thought of putting it off meantime and consist on desktop version only so atleast visitor can see a proper site.

Comment: Disable mobile responsive site?
I don't know why you would want to do that, but generally speaking, mediaqueries are responsible for this. They apply different CSS styling when the viewport is within a specified width. You don't seem to have any media queries though, so I'm not quite sure what you even mean.

Comment: @Maharkus I know what you're thinking. I had a client ask me the same and I was dumbfounded. But sometimes is needed especially if you are working with legacy systems in quirkmode. It's a pain.

Comment: i want to disable mobile responsive because it is not working properly. Thanks for your reply @Maharkus 
one of my friend created the site for me now he disappeared. i tried to resolve the codes to appropriate responsive which currently going totally out of frames here and there in mobile version and i couldn't do it so now i want to fully remove it to make only desktop version still i could not, i am not able to understand the media codes where he used. i am not able find those codes to remove so i need help.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `<meta name="viewport">` from the `<header>` tag, which looks like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

This will disable mobile responsiveness.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i did that but it was not not enough. other than this viewport code there is something in css files also should be removed or adjustable

Comment: @z.ali CSS only includes the media queries, You need to remove all the media query code i.e is inside `@media`.